# Double Integral and Assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I'm afraid this is going to be a really stupid question.

Evaluating the following definite integral

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1 - (x^2 + y^2)], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

gives

```
(2/3) (Pi - I (-2 + Log[4]))
```

I don't want the imaginary part. Adding the option

```
Assumptions -> x^2 + y^2 <= 1
```

doesn't work. What did I miss?

Comment: You try to integrate `Sqrt[1 - (x^2 + y^2)]` over the region where the integrand becomes imaginary (for {x,y} outside the unit circle}), namely you're integrating over a square `(-1,1) x (-1,1)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1 - (x^2 + y^2)] Boole[x^2 + y^2 <= 1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Better:

```
Integrate[r Sqrt[1 - r^2], {r, 0, 1}, {θ, -π, π}]
```

Vastly better:

```
2 π Integrate[r Sqrt[1 - r^2], {r, 0, 1}]
```

Exercise: why?

Comment: Because in the polar coordinates the area outside the integration region is automatically avoided?

Comment: Good show. You're right, @Taiki. :)